# “ImportError: No module named scapy.all” Rasberry PI Rasbian

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, scapy, pcap

I've verified I have scapy installed (ran requirements.txt and installed scapy) I checked my /usr/share/pyshared folder and made sure the scapy install went there. Reinstalled scapy, not sure why I'm still getting this error. I've also tried changing my import to from scapy import * from scapy.all

Comment: A co-worker told me that it could be Rasbian, I'm going to try to re-image the sd and see if it will work on that OS.

Comment: I've tried scapy with Python 2.7 on Raspbian and works fine. Did you install it using pip? How are you importing it?

Comment: from scapy.all import *

Answer (score 0):

What version of python do you have? Scapy works with 2.7. If it doesn't work you should make sure you install it with pip install:

```
pip install scapy
```

The way you import it matters as well, the way to import it is:

```
from scapy.all import *
```

Comment: Doing this exactly, I ended up switching OS to Ubuntu mate and it worked fine :\..